# Laravel unique random string number

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

I would like to make an infinite string with a number. What is the best way to do this here e.g. `mt_rand(1000000, 9000000)` but if between `1000000` and `9000000` everything is occupied there are no more numbers. The more numbers are used the more often there are errors, and the if else has to rattle through the whole table again and again.

```
public function creating(Ticket $ticket)
{
    $randomNumber = mt_rand(1000000, 9000000);

    if(!Ticket::where('number', '=', $randomNumber)->exists()) {
        $ticket->fill(['number' => $randomNumber]);
    } else {
        $this->creating($ticket);
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this? I want it to be a Unique Numberetic String. Which has no end.

Comment: Where is the `creating` method defined?

Comment: Its in a observer when creating

Comment: Do you need only numbers or are alphanumeric strings ok? Ex.: `29b3Fg9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To guarantee a unique number you should instead use `created`. Whenever a ticket is created, you can prepend some random numbers to the id to generate a unique number. Try this

```
public function created(Ticket $ticket) {
    $ticket->number = rand(1000, 9999).str_pad($ticket->id, 3, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $ticket->save();
}
```

Comment: Now its better to use the timestamp see up comment from `Muhammad Tashfeen` or ur... what you are say

Comment: Timestamps are never unique. What if multiple records are to be created at the same time?

Comment: Yes, but what is when between 1000 and 9999 all numbers used with the 3 offsets.. yk

Comment: See `rand(1000, 9999)` is to prepend some random numbers to the `id` you can completely ignore it. The `id` is the real deal. Since it is coming from the database, it is guaranteed to always be unique.